# Trying to run a test code using remote elasticsearch but only localhost connected

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I'm trying to run a test code using remote elasticsearch cluster.
The only configurations that I have are remote ES cluster addresses.

But suddenly my code looking for `localhost:9200` ES cluster.
Any of you knows What happened?

### Logs in test results

#### 1. Prove for remote ES cluster connection (maybe?)

```
2021-09-09 23:48:18.302 DEBUG 52659 --- [    Test worker] org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient      : request [GET http://{my-remote-elasticsearch-host}:{port}/] returned [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
2021-09-09 23:48:18.336  INFO 52659 --- [    Test worker] o.s.d.elasticsearch.support.VersionInfo  : Version Spring Data Elasticsearch: 4.2.3
2021-09-09 23:48:18.337  INFO 52659 --- [    Test worker] o.s.d.elasticsearch.support.VersionInfo  : Version Elasticsearch Client in build: 7.12.1
2021-09-09 23:48:18.337  INFO 52659 --- [    Test worker] o.s.d.elasticsearch.support.VersionInfo  : Version Elasticsearch Client used: 7.12.1
2021-09-09 23:48:18.337  INFO 52659 --- [    Test worker] o.s.d.elasticsearch.support.VersionInfo  : Version Elasticsearch cluster: 7.10.1
2021-09-09 23:48:18.337  WARN 52659 --- [    Test worker] o.s.d.elasticsearch.support.VersionInfo  : Version mismatch in between Elasticsearch Client and Cluster: 7.12.1 - 7.10.1
```

#### 2. Unexpected attempt to the `localhost:9200`

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.NoReachableHostException: Host 'localhost:9200' not reachable. Cluster state is offline.
Caused by: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.NoReachableHostException: Host 'localhost:9200' not reachable. Cluster state is offline.
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.SingleNodeHostProvider.lambda$lookupActiveHost$3(SingleNodeHostProvider.java:101)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.SingleNodeHostProvider$$Lambda$1993/0x0000000000000000.accept(Unknown Source)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:220)
```

### Codes

#### Bean

```java
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        String hostAndPort = new HttpHost(getElasticsearchProperty().getConnectionProperty().getHosts(), Integer.parseInt(getElasticsearchProperty().getConnectionProperty().getPorts())).toHostString();
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
            .connectedTo(hostAndPort)
            .build();
        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }
```

#### Configuration yml

- filename: elasticsearch-local.yml

```yaml
elasticsearch:
  contents:
    connectionProperty:
      hosts: {remote-es-host}
      ports: {remote-port}
      connectionTimeout: 3000
      socketTimeout: 5000
      user: {user}
      password: {password}
```

#### Project structure

- Based on Gradle

```
ㄴ project
  ㄴ project-api
  ㄴ project-elasticsearch
```

##### `project-api`

- Dependent on `project-elasticsearch`
- *NOW I'm trying to run test codes in THIS project.*

##### `project-elasticsearch`

- All configurations or utilities related with Elasticsearch
- I've tried to run test codes in this project, and **successfully connected to the remote ES cluster**.

Comment: I think it relates to your environment configuration, maybe checking the initialization log should help?

Comment: And where is the code? POST THE CODE

Comment: @ThangLeQuoc Isn't the first log I pasted the initialization log? `request GET to my remote ES cluster returned 200`

Comment: @mvmn I added my configuration code and also project structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem to add below in the `project-api`.

```yaml
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: >
      org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchReactiveHealthContributorAutoConfiguration,
      org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ReactiveElasticsearchRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,
      org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ReactiveElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration
```

The problem is that, Spring's autoconfiguration tried to use `ReactiveElasticsearchRestClient` but there were no configurations for the reactive one. So, automatically it tried to connect to the localhost.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the configuration code of Elasticsearch, which according to your assumption should refer to the right host. Anyway, I believe that these links will explain everything you need to know how to configure it (I assume *localhost* is default since you don't configure it as needed).

1. [Rest Elasticsearch config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.nosql.elasticsearch.connecting-using-rest)
2. [High level Client config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.rest)

Comment: I added my configuration code just right now.

Comment: And I also added my project structure. Why I didn't think it is the problem of the configuration is that when I've run test codes in the `project-elasticsearch`, it connected to the remote host as I intended.

Comment: @nullmari 1. Could you please print to the log (or debug) the value of *hostAndPort* immediately after setting the variable?
2. In the project structure, where is the `@Bean public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient()` ?
3. Same question on `elasticsearch-local.yml`

Comment: 2. In the `project-elasticsearch`. 3. same answer.